# Is there a redundant constraint in linear programming?

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, linear-programming

From [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming):

[image: equations image]

But... Why do we need the $x\ge 0$ part? We can instead do $-x\le 0$, and thus saving a line in the definition (which is not a big deal but nevertheless nice).

(In order to do that, we'll need to add lines the lines $-e_i$ for $1\le i\le\dim(x)$ to $A$, in order to get $-x_i\le 0$)

Comment: It's a standard form, for convenience. I think it's mainly to emphasize the connection between a primal and dual LP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, lower and upper bounds on variables can be enforced via explicit constraints.  In practice, however, bounds are handled implicitly because the explicit constraints determine the size of the basis.